# How to use @swimlane/ngx-graph package in angular project version 11.2.5?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, npm-install, ngx-graph

I have created an angular project. The package.json file will look like below :

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "xx",
  "author": {
    "github": "yyy"
  },
  "license": "..;",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "ng": "ng",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --common-chunk --vendor-chunk --optimization --progress",
    "prettier": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/elements": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^11.2.5",
    "@coreui/angular": "^2.11.2",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@coreui/icons-angular": "1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "@formio/angular": "^5.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.1.1",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/event-source-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "@uiowa/digit-only": "^2.4.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^26.2.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^26.2.0",
    "angular-archwizard": "^7.0.0",
    "angular-formio": "^4.11.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "daterangepicker": "^3.1.0",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^1.0.31",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.28",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "leaflet.fullscreen": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-countup": "^7.3.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-permissions": "^8.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "node-forge": "^1.3.1",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.7",
    "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
    "screenfull": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.2.5",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.13",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.7.7",
    "@types/leaflet.fullscreen": "^1.6.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.177",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.33",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.13",
    "npm": ">= 6"
  }
}
```

I have installed the @swimlane/ngx-graph package in my application with following steps :

step 1 : npm i @swimlane/ngx-graph --save

step 2 : Importng NgxGraphModule to my angular application module as below:

My module :

```
.
.
.
import { NgxGraphModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-graph'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
.
.
  ],
  imports: [
.
.
.
    NgxGraphModule
  ],
})
export class FormDesignerModule {}
```

If I add like above , it throes **errors** as below :

```
Error: ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/fesm2015/swimlane-ngx-graph.mjs 3130:12-18
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/fesm2015/swimlane-ngx-graph.mjs 3139:12-18
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/fesm2015/swimlane-ngx-graph.mjs 1644:12-18
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/fesm2015/swimlane-ngx-graph.mjs 3133:12-18
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/fesm2015/swimlane-ngx-graph.mjs 3136:12-18
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/fesm2015/swimlane-ngx-graph.mjs 1187:28-35
Can't import the named export 'Subject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/fesm2015/swimlane-ngx-graph.mjs 1320:28-35
Can't import the named export 'Subject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

.
.
.
Keepon going ...
.
.
.
```

I don't know wy it happens and How to fix this error .

kindly someone help to fix this issue . Thanks in advance